# discord.py - add reacton custom emoij

Tags: discord.py

I have done research and I don't get recent replies (old ones don't work) to add a reaction to a message that will be sent.
The command is "suggest" and is used for suggestions and I need the bot to add reactions (which are personalized emojis) how could I do?

code:

```py
#suggest
@client.command(aleases=["Suggest","SUGGEST","suggerimento","Suggerimento","SUGGERIMENTO","sg","Sg","SG"])
async def suggest(ctx, *,arg):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color=0x03c03c,
        description=f'{arg}',
    )
    channel = client.get_channel(726056722417844395)
    if ctx.channel.id == channel.id:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
        embed.set_author(
            name=f'{ctx.author._user} ha suggerito:',
            icon_url=f'{ctx.author.avatar_url}'
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10)
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color=0x003399,
            description = f'{arg}',
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name=f'Sondaggio proposto da {ctx.author._user}:',
            icon_url=f'{ctx.author.avatar_url}'
        )
        channel = client.get_channel(723938017965768775)
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
        await self.bot.add_reaction(emoji=":Favorevole:") #here's the problem (if it takes the id I don't know how to get the emoij id)
        return
@suggest.error
async def suggest_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color=0xa61022
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name="Inserisci il tuo suggerimento!",
            icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/730639329453670420/DuscePeppe_FRIULI.png"
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10.0)
        return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In discord.py@rewrite, you have to use [`discord.Message.add_reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add_reaction#discord.Message.add_reaction):

```py
@client.command()
async def embed_with_reactions(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="An embed with reactions")
    emojis = ['emoji', ...] #Reactions you want on your message
    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed) #Get the message sent in a variable

    for emoji in emojis:
        await message.add_reaction(emoji) #Add a reaction to the message
```

NB: You'll have to replace `"emoji"` with your emojis. `add_reactions` accepts:

- Global emojis (eg. ) that you can copy on [emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/)
- Raw unicode (eg. "\u2705" for ✅)
- [Discord emojis](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-add-a-reaction-to-a-message): `\N{EMOJI NAME}` (eg. '\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}' for )
- Custom [discord server emojis](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=emoji#discord.Emoji)

  ```py
  def get_emoji(guild: discord.Guild, arg):
       emoji = get(guild.emojis, name=arg)
       return emoji
  ```
- Example:

  ```py
  @commands.command()
  async def test(self, ctx):
      embed = discord.Embed(title="An embed with reactions")
      emojis = [get_emoji(ctx.guild, "Favorevole"), get_emoji(ctx.guild, "Astenuto"), get_emoji(ctx.guild, "Contrario")]
      message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)

      for emoji in emojis:
          await message.add_reaction(emoji)

  def get_emoji(guild: discord.Guild, arg):
      emoji = get(guild.emojis, name=arg)
      return emoji
  ```

Comment: ok the command works (get_emoij) but I have a problem putting it in the reactions. From a strange mistake that I don't understand what it has to do with it.
[ERROR](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/734423665625530368/unknown.png)|[CODE](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/734423754561814669/unknown.png)

Comment: [code and error](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/734431167079514152/unknown.png). I don't understand why he gives me this error when I run the command

Comment: I got the wrong picture sorry [code and errore](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/734434765180239872/unknown.png)

Comment: [code and error](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/734442809414778880/unknown.png). It gives me the same error (but on get_emoji should I put client.command?)

Comment: [code](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/734457758841045012/unknown.png). what function should i write (where i underline)? that `favorevole` in I have in the upper part instead I take it off?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/56sbkPcF I don't understand why you don't get what I'm trying to say

Comment: ok I did it here [code](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/734465442340667443/unknown.png) and [result](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/734465475055976530/unknown.png) but now how do I insert it where the rest was before?

Comment: I tried to do something and now it gives me this error. How can I avoid it? [code and error](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/734478440102756433/unknown.png)

Comment: You can do it this way: https://pastebin.com/xvxaKZzD (Pls delete your old messages, so other people don't get lost/waste their time)